# How to add two signals?

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, continuous-signals, homework

If x(t) is the curve shown in the image

[image]

how can I find (x(2t)+x(2t+2))?

I know how to find the individual terms but don't know how to add them!

And how can I express my answer in terms of the unit step function?

Comment: Add them point-wise; i.e. if the solution is $y(t)$ and $t_0$ is a time instant, then $y(t_0) = x(2t_0)+x(2t_0+2)$. Note that $x(2t_0)$ and $x(2t_0+2)$ are scalars and can be added like any pair of numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First express $x(t)$ in piece-wise form:

$$
x(t) =
\begin{cases}
0 ~&,  \text{ for}  & t  < -2 \\
0.5(t+2) &, \text{ for}  &-2 < t < 0 \\
-t+1 &, \text{ for}  & 0 < t < 1 \\
0 &, \text{ for }   &1 < t \\
\end{cases}
$$

Now, express $x_1(t)=x(2t)$ in a similar form: 
$$
x_1(t) = x(2t) =
\begin{cases}
0 ~&,  \text{ for}  & 2t  < -2 \\
0.5(2t+2) &, \text{ for}  &-2 < 2t < 0 \\
-2t+1 &, \text{ for}  & 0 < 2t < 1 \\
0 &, \text{ for }   &1 < 2t \\
\end{cases}
$$

Recognize how the formula and intervals are adjusted for $x_1(t)$
$$
x_1(t) = x(2t) =
\begin{cases}
0 ~&,  \text{ for}  & t  < -1 \\
t+1 &, \text{ for}  &-1 < t < 0 \\
-2t+1 &, \text{ for}  & 0 < t < 0.5 \\
0 &, \text{ for }   &0.5 < t \\
\end{cases}
$$

Now, express $x_2(t)=x(2t+2)$ in a similar form: 
$$
x_2(t) = x(2t+2) =
\begin{cases}
0 ~&,  \text{ for}  & 2t+2  < -2 \\
0.5(2t+2+2) &, \text{ for}  &-2 < 2t+2 < 0 \\
-(2t+2)+1 &, \text{ for}  & 0 < 2t+2 < 1 \\
0 &, \text{ for }   &1 < 2t+2 \\
\end{cases}
$$

Recognize how the formula and intervals are adjusted for $x_2(t)$ as well
$$
x_2(t) = x(2t+2) =
\begin{cases}
0 ~&,  \text{ for}  & t < -2 \\
t+2 &, \text{ for}  &-2 < t < -1 \\
-2t-1 &, \text{ for}  & -1 < t < -.50 \\
0 &, \text{ for }   &-0.5 < t \\
\end{cases}
$$

Now add those two piecewise defined signals $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$, **considering the intervals** carefully:

$$ y(t) = x_1(t) + x_2(t) = x(2t) + x(2t + 2) =
\begin{cases}
0 ~&,  \text{ for}  & t < -2 \\
t+2 &, \text{ for}  &-2 < t < -1 \\
-t&, \text{ for}  & -1 < t < -0.5 \\
t+1 &, \text{ for }   &-0.5 < t < 0 \\
-2t+1 &, \text{ for}  & 0 < t < 0.5 \\
0 &, \text{ for }   &0.5 < t \\
\end{cases}
$$

Expressing this using unit steps (alone) is not possible, you need the **ramp** functions. Then you can provide a representation using scaled and shifted ramps.

A MATLAB plot of the resulting signal is provided below ;
[image]